# Importing data in database using django

Tags: python, django

I have the resource file look like this.

```
class UmuryangoResource(resources.ModelResource):

    cell = fields.Field(column_name='cell', 
                   attribute='cell',widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Cell, 'name'))

    village = fields.Field(column_name='village', 
                     attribute='village',widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Village, 'name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Umuryango


class Umuryango(models.Model):

    sector = models.ForeignKey(Sector, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cell = models.ForeignKey(Cell, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    village = models.ForeignKey(Village, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='village_cell')
```

The above model field are foreign key, and because cell has it village such that the village can be duplicated in Village model, but assign to different cells. This lead to, when i import xslx file without village has not more than one village_name in a Village it's imported successfully. while my xslx file contain the village__name that has the same name in model. con not be import.

Any one can tell me how i can initialize and save village according to it cell???  and ignore that one from another cell

I have initialize the village field in resource.py but still don't work, any one can help me.